# HTML File Upload Doesn't Show Gallery on Android when add .pdf

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'd like my app to accept an image or PDF file chosen from a user's mobile and when user click on field my add suggests gallery, camera and documents; But now the suggestion list contains video recorder and voice recorder that i don't want these. I'we tried:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*,.pdf" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*,.pdf,capture=camera" capture />
```

Everything works OK on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Easy ! Try this :

```
<input type='file' accept='.jpg,.pdf' capture>
```